# How to pass a class as a function parameter

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to pass a class to a method as a parameter but don`t know if it is possible.

Instead of calling `Insertion class` in the `void runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url)` method, can i pass it as a parameter so that i can add other sorting algorithms.

This is what I have so far:

```
Insertion insertion;

void setup() {
  String url = sketchPath("numbers/512/");
  insertion = new Insertion();
  String[] stringData = null;
  int[] intData = null;
  runTest(stringData, intData, url);
}


void runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url) {

  File directory = new File(url);
  File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    //println(file.getName());
    text = loadStrings(file);
    number = int(text);

    insertion.insertionSort(number);

  }
}



class Insertion {

  Insertion() {
  }

  int[] insertionSort(int[] input) {

    int temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        if (input[j] < input[j-1]) {
          temp = input[j];
          input[j] = input[j-1];
          input[j-1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    println(input);
    return input;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want to do is define a `Sort` interface which contains a `sort()` function:

```
interface Sort{
   public int[] sort(int[] input);
}
```

Then have your `Insertion` class implement your `Sort` interface and its `sort()` function:

```
class Insertion implements Sort{

  Insertion() {
  }

  int[] sort(int[] input) {
      //...
  }
}
```

Do the same for any other sorting classes, and then pass a `Sort` variable into your `runTest` function:

```
void runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url, Sort sortFunction) {

  File directory = new File(url);
  File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    //println(file.getName());
    text = loadStrings(file);
    number = int(text);

    sortFunction.sort(number);
  }
}
```

Since your `Insertion` class (and any other sorting class you've created) implements the `Sort` interface, you can pass instances of them in to your `runTest()` function.

[Here](https://www.processing.org/reference/implements.html) is the Processing reference for implementing an interface.

Answer (score 4):

Create an `interface` called `SortingAlgorithm` and then use it to create multiple implementations of sorting. Something like this:

```
interface SortingAlgorithm {
   public int[] sort(int[]);
}

class BubbleSort implements SortingAlgorithm {
  int[] sort(int[] input) {
      // bubble sort code here
  }
}

class InsertionSort implements SortingAlgorithm {

  InsertionSort() {
  }

  int[] sort(int[] input) {
      return insertionSort(input);
  }

  int[] insertionSort(int[] input) {

    int temp;

    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
        if (input[j] < input[j-1]) {
          temp = input[j];
          input[j] = input[j-1];
          input[j-1] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    println(input);
    return input;
  }
}
```

Now use the algorithms:

```
InsertionSort insertionSort;
BubbleSort bubbleSort;

void setup() {
  String url = sketchPath("numbers/512/");
  insertion = new Insertion();
  String[] stringData = null;
  int[] intData = null;
  runTest(stringData, intData, url, insertionSort);
  runTest(stringData, intData, url, bubbleSort);
}


void runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url, SortingAlgorithm algorithm) {

  File directory = new File(url);
  File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
  for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    //println(file.getName());
    text = loadStrings(file);
    number = int(text);

    algorithm.sort(number);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an Interface for this.

```
public interface SortInterface{
void sortStuff(int[] input);
}
```

Than you can have a lot of different Sorting classes which implement this Interface e.g.

```
class Insertion implements SortInterface
class BubbleSort implements SortInterface
```

All of them have the same method `sortStuff(int[] input)` implemented which you can call in

```
runTest(String[] text, int[] number, String url, SortInterface sortObject)
{
sortObject.sortStuff(number);
}
```